# Auto-lock never missing in IOS 9.2.1

Tags: iphone, ios

Surprised I could not find this asked.

Is there a way to get Auto-Lock "Never" option back in IOS 9.2.1

[image]

Comment: Do you use Touch iD? If so, it's always locked as soon as the screen goes off. The auto-lock setting just becomes a 'time til the screen goes off'.

Comment: I'm on 9.2.1 and I still have the "Never" option. Does it disappear if I unselect it or is there something else that causes it to not be there anymore?

Comment: I do use touch ID, I turned it off and rebooted but still no never option.

Answer (score 3):

Actually i also experienced this. I got this solved because I read a thread regarding this. It's happening because we install some certificate to our iPhone. For me I installed google something management certificate in order to use the google sheets. You can remove it by go to General>Profile.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks for this, cannot confirm to see it it was my case

Answer (score 1):

I found out what it was for me...I only had 30 seconds, 1-minute, and 2-minute options lol.  Couldn't stand it.  It turns out it was a new mail server I added to my iPhone (Exchange acct).  Deleted it and the rest of my settings immediately went back to normal.

Comment: Interesting, wish I could test this, but those days are long gone